# refresh table view when notification is received

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, push-notification, listener

I have a very small chat in my app. whenever a user receives a message, the server sends a notification. In appDelegate I have implemented the code  below:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.alert)
//        print(UNNotificationAction)
        print(" recieved")
        if notification.request.content.title.contains("Message")
        {
            print("sub")
            print(notification.request.content.subtitle)
            print("body")
            print(notification.request.content.body)
            print("it containt DM ⏰")

            let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Chat", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatRoomVc") as! ChatRoomViewController
            vc.becomeFirstResponder()

            vc.setRefreshListener {
                print("triggered")
            }

        }

    }
```

and whenever it runs, it calls the API and gets the chat data.
the code below shows how it gets the data:

```
 func setRefreshListener(listener:@escaping ()->Void){
    refreshListener = listener
    presenter.getttingChatRoomData(aptId: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: userAPTID)!, id: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: userID)!)
    presenter.attachView(view: self)
    super.loadView()
    super.reloadInputViews()
    tableView.reloadData()


}
```

in addition, I can get the data properly.

THE PROBLEM is it does not reload the data for the table view!!

does anybody has any solution why this is happening?

**UPDATE:**
the code below runs when data is recieved:

```
 func gettingUserChatWithSUCCESS(responce: [chatRomModel]) {
        print("✅ getting chat room data SUCCESS")
        data = responce
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: reloadData when you received data from API, implement clsoure to get notification your api data arrived and you can update your tableview after that.

Comment: @ShauketSheikhupdated the question, I have forgotten that part to add it to my question. I have also added a breakpoint but it does not reload the table!

Comment: reload data inside DispatchQueue.main.async { }

Comment: Every time you creating diffrent object of ChatRoomViewController , so it will not work if you want to reload on same viewcontroller just get the root viewcontroller and relaod it.

Comment: you are using it in a wrong way creating VC every time ? and check your tableView numberOfRows delegate method called or not ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can solve this issue using notification observer, Like follow this code.

Add notification observer in your viewcontroller

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onReceiveData(_:)), name: "ReceiveData", object: nil)

@objc func onReceiveData(_ notification:Notification) {
    // Do something now //reload tableview
}
```

call observer using this code in your `appDelegate.swift` file receive notification method

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("ReceiveData"), object: nil)
```

Note:- Remove notification observer when your viewcontrller will Disappear, using this code

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
      NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: "ReceiveData", object: nil)
}
```

Comment: it is causing some sort of crash!!!! after all of these, it changes the text color of all the button in the app to red and disables some of them

Comment: This worked perfectly. The problem is that if I remove the observer on viewWillDisappear it removes it before I call it the next screen I present. How can I remove it then?

Comment: Hi @Jalil Remove observer just before addObserver(First remove existing Observer and add again).

Comment: Hi @AtulParmar ,
What happens when I don't delete it ?

Answer (score 1):

Implement `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` method and post your notification.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background || UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .newMessage, object: nil, userInfo:userInfo)
     }

}
```

In your view controller add an observer to check on notifications (
Add your own selector method.)

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                        selector: #selector(updateMessages(notification:)),
                                        name: .newMessage,
                                        object: nil)



    @objc func updateMessages(notification: NSNotification) {
     // Handle your notifications...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**INCLUDING WITH SWIFT 5.4**

```
let myNotificationKey = "notificationKey" //Declare variable at the global level

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(notifyMe),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: myNotificationKey),
                                       object: nil) //In First VC's viewDidLoad()

func notifyMe() { print("Update tableview") } //In First VC

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: myNotificationKey), object: self) 
//Use this from you want to update the notification center for eg: OnClick of UIButton
```